# What is more useful to find the type of distribution I have, an histogram or a qqplot?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

First, I don't know which data to consider when I talk about the distribution of my data. All my data? **Or each distribution of the data of all the levels of my conditions?** I have tested people three times, and under three levels of learning (high, medium and low). I have histograms of all these three conditions, and as you can see, in the last test every group had plenty of 0s. It could be a zero-inflated distribution? [image: Histograms]

I also made a qqplot of all the scores from all levels of all conditions. [image: qqplot] and they don't seem normal at all.

For what I read, zero inflated is only when you weren't expecting so many zeros, but the third test was a month after and since it is a memory test, I knew I could get plenty of 0s. I don't know what to call a distribution with many expected 0s.

I don't know if it is binomial either because even though each trial can be only correct or incorrect, but I want to know how many out of 12 the got correct at each test.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Could you explain what you plan to do with your characterization of the distribution?  What role would it play in further analyses or in your understanding of the data?  BTW, what you have could arguably be characterized as *censored* data in the sense that your instrument is unable to discriminate among subjects whose "underlying" scores are less than 0 or greater than 24.  Looking at them in this way might give you access to a body of procedures (for dealing with censored data) that could be fruitful.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the brms package in R, which fits Bayesian mixed effects models. I wanted to know the type of distribution I have, to specify a family in the model (the package allows for a bunch of them). My data comes from a memory task. The subjects read 26 phrases and then they have to recall 12 at each time delay (test). Most people got 0 correct after a week. To be more specific, I want to know the distribution to decide what statistical analysis to use.